# Google Reseller Customer Admin User Creation Admin SDK How

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-reseller-api

Google Provisioning API is being replaced by Admin SDK. How can I create a Admin User for my Reseller Customer through Directory API programmatically after creating the customer and subscription through the Google Reseller API. Here is my work flow so far.

- OAuth 2 Access Token is obtained for scopes
    -- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.order
    -- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
- Customer is created and subscription is set to flexible

Now I like to create the first Admin user for the domain.
when i want to insert the admin user for the domain, I get the error API is not enabled.

How can I programmatically enable this domains API and create the Admin user. I like to automate the
user creation for our billing software.

Comment: Reseller can use the new admin SDK to provision resold domain users.  Can you share with us the exact error you got? and the exact API call you made to create the resold domain user?